# Modify XML node but keep the XML file format intact

Tags: java, xml

How may I modify a XML file without any change like attributes ordering, tag expansion and encoding? (My preference is DOM API)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try [VTD-XML](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/).

Since this library builds an index while keeping the file content as-is, its manipulation API will allow to "patch" your file while keeping the rest intact.

Using the VTD-XML API, you will be able to navigate your XML like a DOM tree (even using XPath) and do some modifications (insert elements, insert attributes, etc.)

Comment: I'm also wanting to modify some XMLs and is very important for me to keep the original structure. I was almost giving up when I found this post. VTD-XML really solves my problem. Thank you!!!

Comment: The license is GPL2 so this prevents using this tool in companies developing proprietary software.

Comment: VTD-XML is the rescue - it saved me plenty of working days and I do not need to sit still and spend days in comparing loads of xmls in diff !

Answer (score 2):

One nice option would be using [`decentxml`](https://bitbucket.org/digulla/decentxml/wiki/). I've successfully used it before for programmatically changing a few attributes of a hand-writen XML config file without losing the formatting. It's not DOM, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with DOM, since DOM does not know the attributes' order.

You could use a low-level API such as StAX, javax.xml.stream, but StAX is not exactly comfortable to use.