# How to order elements of an XML after DOM parser using java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I changed the values ​​of an XML file using the DOM api and XPath queries , but the new file created has modified the values ​​correctly but does not maintain the original order of appearance attributes and children of nodes.

They are  XML files quite large and a nodes with a large number of attributes and children

Have you got any experience of how to maintain the original order of occurrence of an XML file using the DOM api changed ?

thanks in advance,

Comment: Please show a snippet of your xml before and after change and some code to go along with it..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know vtd-xml is the only xml lib that maintains the order of original xml byte format in its entirety after parsing/modification.... There is no way DOM can do this..

[Modify XML node but keep the XML file format intact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499011/modify-xml-node-but-keep-the-xml-file-format-intact)